# jQuery map no funciona dentro de un collapse de Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-4, responsive, collapse

Tengo un problema con un collapse y una imagen de tamaño 1380x1800 donde estoy usando la etiqueta `<map>` para seleccionar áreas en específico de la misma.

Además de ello estoy usando la librería de jQuery Maphilight que es para dar efecto de sombra al pasar el cursor por encima de las áreas seleccionadas.

Ahora:

1. La imagen por si sola con la librería de jQuery funciona bien.
2. Cuando ingreso la imagen sola dentro de un collapse sin el uso del `<map>`, ella se ajusta perfectamente al mismo.

**PERO**, cuando quiero ingresar la imagen dentro del collapse **Y** agrego la etiqueta `<map>` dentro del mismo suceden 2 cosas.
mi problema es el siguiente:

1. La imagen se sale del collapse cuando agrego las medidas de las áreas seleccionadas.
2. El efecto de sombra ya no funciona.

¿Hay alguna otra manera de generar el efecto de sombra en las áreas sin que se desajuste la imagen?

Agradezco su ayuda y tiempo al leerme.

> **PD:** Usé `style max-width: 100%` pero no funcionó, aun así la imagen se sale del collapse.

Aquí mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/estilosContenidos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300;1,400&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librerias/fontAwesome/css/all.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..//assets/js/cc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
            $('.map').maphilight();
        }
        );</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTen">
                <h5 class=" mb-0 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-link btn-outline-light collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#collapseTen" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTen">
                        10. Analisis de paladar
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTen" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">                  
                        <div>
                            <img src="../assets/imagenes/muelas.jpeg" style="max-width: 100%;" class="map maphilighted"
                                usemap="#cartaDentalAdulto" /> 
                                <map id="cartaDentalAdulto" name="cartaDentalAdulto">
                                    <!-- parte superior de la carta dental adultos -->
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="209,914,212,901,220,886,229,877,235,873,251,870,261,869,289,877,311,887,322,898,328,912,329,923,329,943,325,953,316,964,301,972,297,973,272,973,259,968,245,962,233,961,223,960,216,954,209,937,208,925" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="220,801,228,786,236,780,241,777,263,776,278,781,291,784,306,787,317,791,331,801,339,816,340,830,335,846,323,862,308,871,287,873,253,864,231,854,219,841,216,829,217,824,219,817" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="242,698,250,689,262,682,295,682,317,688,335,696,343,705,349,714,353,729,353,751,347,765,338,776,326,782,310,784,293,781,275,776,260,770,248,764,239,756,235,750,233,746,233,730,234,721" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="262,654,267,660,278,673,293,679,309,684,325,686,359,684,372,673,378,661,378,646,373,636,365,627,351,618,330,609,311,604,285,604,269,615,262,629" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="291,570,294,579,303,589,315,597,329,603,347,608,356,610,377,611,388,606,396,598,403,586,403,572,395,558,386,548,376,540,365,534,351,528,338,523,315,523,301,533,294,542" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="344,503,344,512,350,520,357,526,369,532,378,536,387,538,400,540,410,542,418,545,424,545,432,540,441,531,447,522,452,512,452,502,445,491,438,480,431,470,424,461,414,451,404,446,389,447,378,454,367,463,358,475,350,489" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="419,434,422,444,426,451,431,458,439,467,449,477,457,485,463,491,476,491,489,484,498,477,504,470,503,414,501,409,496,401,488,393,468,393,456,397,444,403,432,411,424,418,419,424" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="507,369,519,363,532,359,575,359,588,365,595,373,599,381,598,405,594,416,588,428,584,438,580,446,576,452,569,455,560,457,533,457,526,453,520,441,508,416,502,400,501,378" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="603,381,603,403,612,428,621,447,629,454,639,457,663,457,673,454,678,447,688,427,698,400,698,376,690,367,677,361,668,359,627,360,615,365,607,372" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="712,394,703,403,697,414,696,418,694,428,694,471,699,479,705,483,719,491,725,493,735,493,757,472,768,459,773,452,778,442,778,426,766,412,747,400,734,395,722,393" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="796,444,784,450,774,459,768,468,759,487,754,498,750,509,751,517,760,531,771,541,780,546,787,546,797,542,812,536,826,531,839,524,850,516,856,508,856,495,850,483,841,471,826,457,814,449,804,444 " />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="846,528,825,535,809,543,792,557,781,574,781,589,789,604,805,615,823,615,848,610,873,598,888,584,892,573,892,559,889,548,882,537,867,528" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="889,601,871,604,847,613,827,626,817,637,813,646,813,660,820,673,828,681,841,685,863,685,891,679,905,674,914,669,921,662,926,653,929,647,929,629,925,619,917,608,904,602" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="907,677,898,679,869,687,856,694,848,702,843,712,840,721,839,747,844,761,853,771,863,777,875,780,887,780,901,778,940,760,954,749,958,739,958,723,955,706,950,694,943,685,936,680,926,677" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="928,769,904,778,883,785,872,793,864,801,858,809,857,827,862,842,869,852,877,859,894,867,911,867,958,850,970,841,977,829,978,815,975,810,975,793,970,783,962,775,951,769" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="936,862,960,862,976,872,984,884,989,901,990,921,989,932,984,942,974,949,959,952,947,957,934,961,920,964,900,964,885,956,876,945,871,932,872,902,877,893,884,883,896,875,915,868" />
                
                                    <!-- parte inferior de la carta dental adultos -->
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="895,1107,908,1103,934,1104,964,1116,976,1118,987,1123,992,1132,995,1140,994,1162,990,1181,980,1196,966,1205,946,1207,902,1194,888,1184,883,1177,877,1155,875,1138,883,1120,889,1113" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="900,1201,913,1202,932,1206,955,1217,972,1228,979,1241,979,1254,977,1262,976,1272,972,1286,962,1295,944,1301,927,1300,881,1283,864,1269,858,1255,859,1239,871,1217,884,1206,892,1202" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="851,1299,864,1292,880,1290,895,1292,913,1300,945,1322,955,1337,953,1361,941,1388,927,1401,934,1396,921,1404,893,1401,858,1385,842,1370,837,1355,837,1333,840,1316" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="820,1415,829,1402,839,1395,852,1393,868,1395,910,1413,924,1425,931,1437,930,1456,921,1475,911,1482,891,1484,859,1473,839,1459,822,1440,819,1428" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="778,1488,783,1476,792,1466,804,1462,821,1462,848,1472,863,1479,875,1488,883,1498,886,1510,886,1523,877,1542,864,1552,842,1552,816,1543,793,1524,779,1509,777,1496" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="768,1528,786,1535,811,1543,833,1559,838,1565,838,1574,822,1598,798,1617,786,1622,770,1620,759,1612,743,1589,732,1563,737,1550,744,1540,756,1532" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="687,1589,699,1576,709,1570,716,1568,722,1571,734,1588,748,1604,755,1621,755,1635,739,1654,713,1668,701,1667,690,1654,688,1645,687,1604" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="625,1600,634,1596,643,1592,660,1593,668,1602,681,1635,684,1647,683,1673,675,1685,659,1691,628,1690,616,1683,610,1672,609,1650,613,1632,620,1611" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="547,1598,556,1593,575,1594,588,1600,605,1646,606,1667,596,1686,576,1692,545,1688,530,1677,528,1659,530,1645,543,1609" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="494,1570,506,1572,522,1584,526,1592,525,1644,519,1661,511,1668,499,1668,473,1654,457,1636,458,1620,466,1602,477,1588" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="393,1550,403,1544,414,1540,450,1531,463,1537,474,1553,480,1567,473,1582,462,1599,447,1619,434,1625,423,1624,405,1611,391,1596,382,1578,380,1566,385,1557" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="326,1501,339,1487,358,1476,376,1470,395,1466,412,1469,422,1475,432,1492,432,1507,414,1530,390,1547,361,1556,341,1554,330,1544,323,1527,322,1513" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="300,1413,330,1402,358,1399,373,1399,384,1406,396,1424,396,1439,390,1449,377,1461,346,1479,320,1483,297,1479,282,1460,281,1440,285,1427,293,1418" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="251,1329,262,1322,276,1315,300,1306,314,1303,333,1304,349,1311,360,1327,363,1346,360,1372,345,1390,322,1400,293,1408,273,1407,255,1392,245,1363,244,1344,249,1337" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="223,1237,236,1226,252,1220,274,1215,300,1213,319,1219,332,1233,340,1254,339,1272,328,1290,312,1299,260,1315,236,1308,222,1292,216,1273,218,1263,218,1248" />
                                    <area shape="poly" href="#"
                                        coords="244,1123,262,1115,278,1110,301,1110,319,1118,329,1132,333,1151,332,1165,325,1184,307,1200,268,1213,245,1214,225,1201,215,1173,212,1151,220,1130,230,1125" />
                                </map>                               
                        </div>
                   
                </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../librerias/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```